# почему Не работает SignalR

Tags: flutter, dart, signalr

Всем привет, я написал клиентскую часть signalR -

```
 final serverUrl = "http://serverUrl:port/paymenthub";
                final defaultHeaders = MessageHeaders();
                defaultHeaders.setHeaderValue("CashDeskId", "40089");
              try {
                final connection = HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl(serverUrl,
                    options: HttpConnectionOptions(
                      logMessageContent: true,
                      // headers: defaultHeaders,
                    )).withAutomaticReconnect().build();

                await connection.start();


                connection.on("GetPaymentConfirmation", ([user, amount, transactionId]) {
                  print(user);
                  print(amount);
                  print(transactionId);
                });

              } catch (error){
                print(error);
              }

                  int a = 0;
```

Этот код не выдает ошибок, смотрел под дебагом, вроде все тоже ок.

Раньше, до того, как я засунул айпишник в переменную - я получал ошибку -
`SocketException: Connection refused (OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111), address = 127.0.0.1:port` Но, сейчас этой ошибки нет (не знаю почему, потому что я засунул айпишник в переменную или нет)
Я не пытаюсь подключиться к локальному хосту! Я пытаюсь подключиться к серверу

Мне нужна помощь, ведь я действительно не понимаю, в чем моя ошибка. Консоль совершенно пуста(
Суть ошибки - я не подключаюсь к хабу.

Comment: Я не понял, а о засовывает какого ip и в какую переменную идёт речь? Кроме того, Вы пишете вопрос только про клиентскую сторону, а что у Вас происходит на сервере?

Comment: первую часть вопроса я не понял. Что касается  сервера, я не знаю, писал не я. Но есть клиентский код на с# который работает, его писали для теста и он практически идентичен этому